# How to generate Amazon S3 image thumb path for Symfony Sonata Media in controller

Tags: symfony, amazon-s3, sonata-media-bundle

I need to generate Amazon S3 media thumb inside Symfony2 controller using Sonata Media Bundle.

This is my config.yml related to sonata_media

```
sonata_media:
    default_context: default
    db_driver: doctrine_orm
    contexts:
        default:
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.image
                - sonata.media.provider.file
            formats:
                small: { width: 100 , quality: 90}
                medium: { width: 500 , quality: 90}
                big:   { width: 1000 , quality: 90}
        image:
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.image
                - sonata.media.provider.file
            formats:
                small: { width: 100 , quality: 90}
                medium: { width: 500 , quality: 90}
                big:   { width: 1000 , quality: 90}
        resource:
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.file
            formats:
                medium: { width: 500 , quality: 90}
    providers:
        image:
            filesystem: sonata.media.filesystem.s3
            resizer: sonata.media.resizer.square
        file:
            filesystem: sonata.media.filesystem.s3
            resizer:    false
```

Inside my controller I'm trying to use something like this:

```
        $provider = $this->container->get("sonata.media.provider.image");
        $url      = $provider->generatePublicUrl($media, 'small');
```

but value returned is this

```
        /uploads/media/image/0001/01/thumb_1_small.jpeg
```

and not the Amazon S3 Media thumb.

Any suggestion?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to set the cdn server path, by default is: "/uploads/media".

If you are using Amazon S3 your path should be: "http://YOUR_REGION/YOUR_BUKET_NAME"

This is my sonata_media.yml (imported in config.yml)

```
imports:
     - { resource: amazon_s3_parameters.yml }
sonata_media:
    default_context: default
    db_driver: doctrine_orm 
    contexts:
        guideimage:
            providers:
                    - sonata.media.provider.image
            formats:
                thumbnail: { width: 128 , quality: 100}
                big: { width: 1500 , quality: 100}
        default:
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.image
                - sonata.media.provider.file
            formats:
    cdn:
        server:
            path: http://%s3_region%/%s3_bucket_name%
    filesystem:
        s3:
            bucket:     %s3_bucket_name%
            accessKey:  %s3_access_key%
            secretKey:  %s3_secret_key%
            region:     %s3_region%
            storage:    standard
            acl:        public
            create:     true
            encryption: aes256
            cache_control: max-age=86400
```

Of course %s3_region% and %s3_bucket_name% are parameters, in my case:

```
s3_region: s3.amazonaws.com
s3_bucket_name: mybucket
```